# Using Hölder's Inequality to prove the following equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

Here $B_r$ presents the open ball of radius r in $R^3$. So I hope to know how to prove the following inequality.
$$
\int_{B_r} |u|\le Cr^{\frac{9}{5}}\left(\int_{B_r} |u|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}\left(\int_{B_r} |u|^3\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}
$$
I did not figure out where these exponents come from. Could anyone show me?

Comment: Write $|u| = |u|^{2/5} |u|^{3/5} 1^{3/5}$ and apply Holder's inequality with exponents $(1/5,1/5,3/5)$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Hi thanks and just now I have come out about it... :)

Comment: @PeterHumphries Excuse me and in fact I am now stuck at this question [bound](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417748/constant-bound-for-the-1-dimensional-besicovitch-covering-theorem-on-real-line), and it would be much appreciative if any suggestions could be given. Thanks!~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have got the answer… it is quite a simple result from the Hölder inequality,
$u^{\frac{2}{5}}u^{\frac{3}{5}}1$ with exponents $\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{3}{5}$….

Comment: Mentioned [earlier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418194/using-holder-inequality-to-prove-the-following-equation#comment1073492_418194) by @PeterHumphries.

Comment: @LSpice Yeah.. I was just typing and did not notice that someone has already posted it.. :)